# R data.table NA type consistency

Tags: r, data.table, na

```
dt = data.table(x = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))
dt[, y := if(.N > 2) .N else NA, by = x] # fail
dt[, y := if(.N > 2) .N else NA_integer_, by = x] # good
```

This first grouping fails because `NA` has a type and it's not integer. Is there a way to tell data table to ignore that and try to make all NAs to whatever type that keeps consistency?

I can manually set `NA_integer` here, but if I have lots of columns of different types, it's hard to set all NA type correct.

BTW, what NA type should I use for Date/IDate/ITime?

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm sure second one works. Are you using RStudio? RStuidio sometimes keeps saying previous error message when successfully executed new commands.

Comment: @RichardScriven oh, I see why. Don't execute the two in sequence. The failed command actually changes the table

Comment: Your "x" column is not an "integer" -- I guess the "integer" is needed because of `.N`, so, using `.N` as the returned value, you could hardcode `NA_integer_` for different `typeof`s. In other cases set the `storage.mode` of your returned value (here `NA`) to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 3):

> **OP's first question:** Is there a way to tell data table to ignore that and try to make all NAs to whatever type that keeps consistency?

No. You'll see a similar error without the assignment:

```
dt[, if(.N > 2) .N else NA, by = x]
#  Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , if (.N > 2) .N else NA, by = x) : 
# Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

In my opinion, this "Column types must be consistent for each group." message should be shown for your case as well.

---

> **OP's second question:** BTW, what NA type should I use for Date/IDate/ITime?

For IDate et al, I always subset by `NA_integer_`, which seems to give a length-one NA slice, e.g., `as.IDate(Sys.Date())[NA_integer_]`. I don't know if that's what one *should* do, but I don't know of a better idea. An illustration:

```
z = IDateTime(factor(Sys.time()))
#         idate    itime
# 1: 2016-08-01 16:05:25

str( lapply(z, function(x) x[NA_integer_]) )
# List of 2
#  $ idate: IDate[1:1], format: NA
#  $ itime:Class 'ITime'  int NA
```

Comment: The subsetting way doesn't work for ITime -- works for IDate

Comment: @jf328 I've edited in an example showing how I use it and the sense in which I think it "works". Could you be more specific? For me, it's enough that the class attribute is preserved.

Comment: `as.ITime("00:00:01")[NA_integer_]` gets an error -- data.table issue I guess?

Comment: @jf328 Yeah, it may be a bug in an earlier version. If it's a serious problem for you and you'r willing to use the unstable/devel version, installation instructions are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation Using that version, it works fine for me.